# BIRT : Filter cascaded Report Parameter group based on Local Report Parameter

Tags: java, reporting, birt

I want to design BIRT report such that in my case user will enter start time and stop time , based on start time and stop time I will get list of available batch name  present between start time and stop time.
And afterwards user will select Batch name from combo box to view detail information. I have tried with cascading report parameter group but based on start time and stop time report parameter batch list is not getting filtered.

Comment: 1. The created report needs to be in HTML. 2. The selected /added filters from combobox - report parameters should dynamically hit query with just entered filters.. Meaning...new query with new filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your Birt version, but, you can use the cascading parameters for that, try that :
I assumed you have 2 or 3 datasets : one (or two) to get your start time & end time, and another one to get your batch name.
Select a multiple Data set when you are creating your new cascading parameter :
[image]

Then, add your two parameters : start time & end time with the data set you created
And, for the Batch Name, then, create another dataset like :

[image]

And then, stay in the dataset, go in the parameter tab and add your two parameters you want :

[image]

This should work