# How to create ALL or SINGLE select parameters in BIRT?

Tags: sql, eclipse, parameters, birt, cascading

I am having 4 Report parameters and these are linked with the 4 datasets individually.
All 4 parameters are hierarchically linked.
For eg:
Country-->State-->City-->Town.
I need to select a Country name firstly and then automatically it has to filter the next parameter list(State parameter) by default 'ALL' and also manually it has to allow me to select 'single'  state. Likewise city, town too..

I tried with stored procedures :

State = IIF(@State='0',State, @State) , similarly the other two as well.

This is giving me results in SQL but not allowing me to select single parameters without default value under country parameter in BIRT.

Please help me in this as it is an immediate requirement.

Comment: You didn't mention the database.

Comment: All were from the same database - SQL

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647027/birt-filter-cascaded-report-parameter-group-based-on-local-report-parameter

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't match my requirement..!
I have to select ALL or ONE option in the parameters dropdown list.